# Performing calculations using a class and referencing form controls

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn classes, meaning writing codes outside of the windows form and calling that code in the form. I created a basic calculation in the form and it works. The problem is, I want to know how I can move the entire calculation into a class and call it into the form on load or when a control is click. It does not work!

**Here is my local or form version which works:**
Please note that the form will load with the first calculation because the Radiobutton is checked on load.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculations
{
    public partial class Calculations : Form
    {
        public Calculations()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public  decimal SalesTax = 0.065M;
        public  decimal AppliedTax;
        public  decimal Price;
        public  decimal SubTotal;
        public  decimal GrandTotal;


        public object Calc()
        {
            Int32 GetQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
            SubTotal = (Price * GetQuantity);
            AppliedTax = (SubTotal * SalesTax);
            GrandTotal = (SubTotal + AppliedTax);

            if (radRed.Checked == true)
            {
                Price = 100;
            }

            else if (radBlue.Checked == true)
            {
                Price = 200;
            }

            else if (radGreen.Checked == true)
            {
                Price = 300;
            }

            lblPrice.Text = GrandTotal.ToString("c");

            return GrandTotal;
        }


        private void Calculations_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtQuantity.Text = "10";
            radRed.Checked = true;
            Calc();

        }

        private void radRed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calc();
        }

        private void radBlue_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            Calc();

        }

        private void radGreen_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calc();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
          Calc();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt to place all of this in a class:
It works but not on load, you have to check another radiobutton first

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculations
{
    class ClsCalc
    {
        class ClsRef
        {
            public static Calculations FormCtrls
            {
                get
                {
                    return Calculations.ActiveForm as Calculations;
                }
            }
        }

        public static decimal SalesTax = 0.065M;
        public static decimal AppliedTax;
        public static decimal Price;
        public static decimal SubTotal;
        public static decimal GrandTotal;


        public static object Calc()
        {
            Int32 GetQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(ClsRef.FormCtrls.txtQuantity.Text);
            SubTotal = (Price * GetQuantity);
            AppliedTax = (SubTotal * SalesTax);
            GrandTotal = (SubTotal + AppliedTax);

            if (ClsRef.FormCtrls.radRed.Checked == true)
            {
                Price = 100;
            }

            else if (ClsRef.FormCtrls.radBlue.Checked == true)
            {
                Price = 200;
            }

            else if (ClsRef.FormCtrls.radGreen.Checked == true)
            {
                Price = 300;
            }

            ClsRef.FormCtrls.lblPrice.Text = GrandTotal.ToString("c");

            return GrandTotal;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I called it in the form Load event:

> ClsCalc.Calc();

Please note this is not a real project just a way to learn, well for me that is.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation method is almost entirely involving interactions with UI elements.  You gather a bunch of information from a textbox and various checkboxes, and then have just three lines of actual calculations, and then you display the results.

UI interaction *shouldn't* be moved outside of the form.  You shouldn't expose the internal controls of a form publicly; they should only ever be accessed from within their parent form (or user control, if that's the case).

A common pattern that you'll see when performing some form submit operation is to gather information from input controls, do some calculations on the data, and then display the results on the form.  Both the gathering information and displaying results should stay within the form, the only thing that you should (potentially) move outside of the form's definition is the calculations.  In this case that's such a small amount of work there just isn't a compelling reason to do that.

Comment: Very helpful, so based on your second paragraph, about exposing the form element, how do you recommend calling form elements in a class without making the controls public?

Comment: @UnaverageGuy You *don't*.  That's the point.  The form should be the only class ever accessing the child controls directly.